# Declare JavaScript variable only with ' ' marks

Tags: javascript, variables, declare

I saw one of the masters doing this:

```
var example = '';
```

Then later he continued with this:

```
example += '<div>just a div</div>';
```

I wanna know if there's any difference from doing this:

```
var example;

example += '<div>just a div</div>';
```

I don't really know if by doing the second method I'm doing wrong and I have to code like shown if the first example.

---

Updated!

Thank you so much for your answers, Ok I got it I need to define my variable to be able to work woth it, but then another question came... This master also is doing this:

```
var guess;
```

and then he does:

```
guess += myfunction( upper );
```

where myfunction was declared as follows:

```
function myFunction( upper ){
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * upper ) + 1;
}
```

So, why here is different? Can any of you answer this please?

Thank you!

---

Second update!

Again Thanks!

I decided to post the whole code the JS master was doing, at this point I don't understand, so probably you'll be able to clear my doubts.

```
var randomNumber = myFunction( 10 );
var guess;
var attempts = 0;
var answer = false;

function myFunction( upper ){
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * upper ) + 1;
}

do{
    guess = prompt( "I created a number from 1 till 10, can you guess it?");
    attempts += 1;
    if( parseInt( guess ) === randomNumber ){
        answer = true;
    }
}while( ! answer )
    document.write( "Took you " + attempts + " attempts to guess the number " + randomNumber);
```

Please have a look at:

```
var guess;
```

and how later is being declared, so why here works perfectly but in my first example I have to put the '' when declaring my variable?

I hope my question is clear enough for you!

Thank you for your time and patient!

Comment: There's no difference between your first pair of code examples and `var example = '<div>just a div</div>';` There are reasons to do things that way, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
var example;

example += '<div>just a div</div>';
```

You end up with:

```
`"undefined<div>just a div</div>"`
```

This is because when you don't initialize a variable, it is `undefined`, which can be converted to a sensible string `"undefined"` when you try to add it to another string.

When you do:

```
var guess;

guess += myfunction( upper );

function myFunction( upper ){
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * upper ) + 1;
}
```

You are adding a `number` to `undefined`. This results in `NaN` (not a number) because `undefined` cannot be converted into a sensible `number`.

You can check this yourself next time by opening up your browser's developer tools and running the code in the console.

**Edit:**

When you do:

```
var guess;

guess = prompt( "I created a number from 1 till 10, can you guess it?");
```

There's no issue because you are simply assigning a `string` to the `guess` variable. In the previous examples you were adding something to a variable, which means if they are different types then JavaScript has to try to do something sensible.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I saw also he was doing this: var example; then he continued with: example += 2; In this case, which one is the difference then? Thank you!

Comment: I updated my question, again... If you can give me a hand again, will be highly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi @Frank Thanks so much! I have a new question, I'm sorry about it, as you can see I'm learning and I really wanna get it right :)... When you say: "JavaScript has to try to do something sensible" What exactly means that? What is sensible in JavaScript? Can you explain that to me or tell me where can I get more info about it? Thanks so much!

Comment: JS is a dynamic language - a variable can hold one type like a `string` now, and a different type like a `number` later. When you add different types together JS won't give an error like a statically typed language, but it has to try to convert one type into the other so the addition makes sense (but the result may not be what you expect, as seen in my answer). You can also compare different types like `if ("1" == 1)` which returns true, but a strict comparison like `if ("1" === 1)` returns false. Read more about dynamic typing, comparison operators, type conversions, and JS in general.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't initialize your variable it has a value of undefined.

In your last example, you are really saying `example = undefined + '<div>just a div</div>'` and undefined will be converted to a string and output that way.  Probably not what you want.

In general it is a good idea to initialize your variables before you use them which is why `var example = ''` is preferable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myvar
myvar += 'asdf'
console.log(myvar) // prints undefinedasdf

var othervar = ''
othervar += 'sdfasdf'
console.log(othervar) // prints sdfasdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialize the variable then it will be `undefined`
Appending to undefined object doesn't help.

```
var example = '';
```

Here you are initializing an empty string to the variable and therefore appending a string to another string will give the desired output of string concatenation.

Output:

```
"undefined<div>just a div</div>"
"<div>just a div</div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference  the first snipet from the master creates a variable example and gives it a default  value, the second statement  concatinates the value with 'just a div'
.Your code has an error as it is adding a value to a non-existed value as variable  example has no default  value.